# Adding 'nonce' in API Request- R

Tags: r, nonce

I'm trying to build a request in R for the exchange platform Exmo which requires authentification and a Nonce.(https://exmo.com/en/api#/authenticated_api) I have tried several codes but keep getting the same error.

My code is:

```
query <-    
  list(    
    nonce = as.numeric(as.POSIXct(Sys.time()))    
  )    

signature <-    
    digest::hmac(    
    key = "secretkey",      
    object = paste(names(query), query, sep = "=", collapse = "&"),        
    algo = "sha512"           
  )        

(acc <- POST(        
  url= "https://api.exmo.com/v1/user_info/",        
  add_headers(Key = "publickey"),        
  add_headers(Sign = "secret key"),        
  add_headers(nonce=nonce),        
  query = c(signature = signature),        
  verbose()        
))        

library(jsonlite)        
get_exmo<- content(acc, as="text")      # Convert to "character"        
(get_exmo_json <- fromJSON(get_exmo))
```

The error I get is:

$`result`
[1] FALSE

$error
[1] "40007: Incorrect format parameter 'nonce'"

Any ideas how to add the right format of nonce?

Answer (score 0):

The nonce goes in the request URL, not in the headers, judging from this part of https://github.com/exmo-dev/exmo_api_lib/blob/master/python/exmo3.py#L21:

```
def api_query(self, api_method, params = {}):
    params['nonce'] = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
    params =  urllib.parse.urlencode(params)

    sign = self.sha512(params)
    headers = {
        "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Key": self.API_KEY,
        "Sign": sign
    }
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(self.API_URL)
    conn.request("POST", "/" + self.API_VERSION + "/" + api_method, params, headers)
    response = conn.getresponse().read()
```